# Read text files long text file in python

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I have a text file like this:

```
Header...
40x1 matrix
# Comment1
# Comment 2
36x1 matrix
# Comment 1
# Comment 2
40x 36 matrix
# Comment 1
40x 36 matrix
# Comment 1
40x 36 matrix
```

Now I want to read `40x1` matrix, `36x1` matrix separately, and loop through each `40x36` matrix.

Could anyone offer some help?

Regards
Barack

Comment: It is not very clear how your file is structured. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: Sorry, here is an example of the file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/uu7u87mthur4thn/files.txt?dl=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the # lines as a separation between your matrix. So if you loop line by line on your file, you can separate the matrix with this # lines, and built them :

```
file = open("file.txt", "r")
lines = file.readlines()
```

At this point, lines is a list. lines[i] is the line n° i+1 as a string.

```
# k, a counter to loop on the lines
k = 1
# Matrix_list is a list of the matrix (size i*j) like that [40*1, 36*1, ...]
Matrix_list = []
while k < len(lines):
    if "#" in lines[k-1] and "#" not in lines[k]:
        # Start a new matrix
        row = []

        # Loop to get all the lines of the current matrix
        while "#" not in lines[k]:

            if k > len(lines):
                break

            row.appends(lines[k])
            k +=1

        # At this point, row is a list of every row of your matrix
        # First we get the matrix size i*j and create a matrix
        i = len(row)
        j = len(row[0].split())
        Mat = np.zeros((i, j))

        row_position = 0

        for elt in row:
            colum_position = 0
            L = elt.split()
            for data in L:
                Mat[row_position, colum_position] = data
                colum_position += 1
            row_position +=1

         # Once all the data you had was palced in the matrix : 
         Matrix_list.append(Mat)

    else:
        k += 1
```

Well I hope you get the idea of the algorithm, though i'm pretty sure it won't work right away. Need to do some test and adjustments, but the global idea should do the trick. At the end you'll have Matrix_list, a list with every matrix of your txt file as a numpy array.

Once you have that, well you can do whatever you want with each matrix.